# Nagios timeperiod and notification period

Tags: nagios

I'm having troubles getting Nagios to honor a notification_period setting for a predefined timeperiod.

My timeperiod definition is called 'sleep' as in, do not notify me between midnight and 7am. it looks like this:

```
 define timeperiod{
    timeperiod_name sleep
    alias           Not Middle of Night
    sunday          07:00-23:59
    monday          07:00-23:59
    tuesday         07:00-23:59
    wednesday       07:00-23:59
    thursday        07:00-23:59
    friday          07:00-23:59
    saturday        07:00-23:59
    }
```

I've entered the directive for the hosts as follows:

```
define host{
    use             linux-server,host-pnp
    host_name       server.domain.com
    alias           server.domain.com
    address         xxx.33.xxx.243
    notification_period     sleep
    }
```

This morning I was expecting to see WARNING notifications but only after 7am. Instead, I saw them throughout the night between 23:59 last night and 7am this morning.

My understanding from the configuration is that I should NOT have received any emails during this time.

Have I overlooked something? I was hoping it would be this simple but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 7):

I have solved this issue which stemmed from a lack of understanding of the way Nagios is configured. In short, custom service checks require custom notification_period directives if desired.

The question was asked and correctly answered in detail here:

[Nagios Forum: notification_period not honoured on host config?](http://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=9680)

Comment: just a little note about the notification period for a host: This directive is used to specify the short name of the time period during which notifications of events for this host can be sent out to contacts. **If a host goes down, becomes unreachable, or recoveries** during a time which is not covered by the time period, no notifications will be sent out. (according to the [official doc](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#host). So it doesn't concern service notification

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint. Please, check your time and time zone setting on the Nagios server. Your configuration looks fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the time is correct on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding it to all your service checks.  You can add it to you contact or contact_group having the email addresses that should be notified during that time.  I do basically the same for two different groups because we are 24X7.  The US group gets the notifications during EST days, and the Asian group gets them at night.  Saving everyone a lot of needless alert spam.